# How to determine a set of conclusions that can be derived from a set of premises?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Considering the following three premises.
How is it possible to determine the set of conclusions that can be derived from the given set of premises.

```
P1 ⟺ A → (B → C)
P2 ⟺ A ∨ ((B ∧ C) ∨ (¬B ∧ ¬C))
P3 ⟺ B → C
```

Comment: We're probably going to need to bound this somehow -- you can create infinitely many conclusions by constructing new propositions trivially, i.e., from P3 I can create a new proposition $(B\implies C) \land (B\implies C)$, or even $(B\implies C)\land (B\implies C)\land (B\implies C)$. 

I suppose we're looking for a minimal set, like the result of taking the Karnaugh map simplification over A, B, and C

Comment: From $P_1$ and $P_3$, we can see that clearly knowing $A$ doesn't give us anything new of interest. So the only real thing left to consider is the second case of $P_3$, which you can show to be equivalent to $B\iff C$. So you get $A \lor (B\iff C)$. Taking $P_3$ into account, you can reduce this to just $A \lor (C\implies B)$ I suppose. I'm not sure what else you might want.

Comment: @JackCrawford: So I should create a formula $\phi$ by linking all three premises with logical OR $\phi = (P_1 \lor P_2 \lor P_3)$, fill out the truth-table of $\phi$, convert this truth-table into a '[karnaugh map](https://youtu.be/UfZKvPQku8w?t=210)' and finally read out the conclusions?

Comment: Potentially, although on second thought, I'm not sure Karnaugh maps simplify over implication statements so this could actually be a red herring. The challenge here is knowing what you actually mean when you say "the set of conclusions", because there are of course lots of trivial ways these statements can be rearranged without really adding any value. As I noted above, basically the most interesting thing you can derive from this is that $A\lor (C\implies B)$, which isn't much. What constraints would satisfy you as a complete-enough set of conclusions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

At first the CNF of all premises has to be derived 
(in my case I am using a truth-table to do so).

```
| ABC | B→C | A→P_3 | B∧C | ¬B∧¬C | A∨E∨F | CNF(P_1)       | CNF(P_2)       | CNF(P_3)       |
|---- |---- |------ |---- |------ |------ |--------------- |--------------- |--------------- |
|     | P_3 |  P_1  |  E  |   F   |  P_2  |                |                |                |
| 000 |  1  |   1   |  0  |   1   |   1   |                |                |                |
| 001 |  1  |   1   |  0  |   0   |  (0)  |                | (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C) ∧ |                |
| 010 | (0) |   1   |  0  |   0   |  (0)  |                | (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)   | (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ |
| 011 |  1  |   1   |  1  |   0   |   1   |                |                |                |
| 100 |  1  |   1   |  0  |   1   |   1   |                |                |                |
| 101 |  1  |   1   |  0  |   0   |   1   |                |                |                |
| 110 | (0) |  (0)  |  0  |   0   |   1   | (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)  |                | (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)  |
| 111 |  1  |   1   |  1  |   0   |   1   |                |                |                |
```

Than linking the three CNFs into one general CNF.

```
CNF(P_1) = (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)
CNF(P_2) = (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C) ∧ (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)  
CNF(P_3) = (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)
CNF = (P_1) ∧ (P_2) ∧ (P_3)
CNF = (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C) ∧ (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)
```

Finally derive the set of conclusions `C` from the general CNF:

```
C_1 = (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)
C_2 = (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C)
C_3 = (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)
C_4 = (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C)
C_5 = (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)
C_6 = (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C) ∧ (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)
C_7 = (¬A ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C) ∧ (A ∨ ¬B ∨ C)  

C = {C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5, C_6, C_7}
```